# one dense set problem in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{P_n}=\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{2i}:a_i\in\mathbb{R} \} \subseteq C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$.
Is  $\mathbb{P_n}$ dense in $C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2):

Members of $\mathbb P_n$ are even functions. Suppose you are trying to approximate $f(x) = x$, and $\epsilon  > 0$ is very small. Any member $p \in \mathbb P_n$ such that $$\lvert p(1) - f(1) \rvert < \epsilon$$ satisfies $p(1) > 1-\epsilon$. But then $p(-1) = p(1) > 1-\epsilon$, and so $$\lvert p(-1) - f(-1)\rvert = p(-1) + 1 > 2-\epsilon$$ which cannot be made arbitrarily small. Thus members of $\mathbb P_n$ cannot approximate the continuous function $f(x) = x$ uniformly.

Comment: thank you so much. I understand :D

Comment: @Yavrumus you’re welcome! As an aside, this question is related to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which gives a succinct set of conditions for a sub collection of $C([-1,1], \mathbb R)$ to be dense. One condition is that the collection “separate points”, meaning that for any different points $x,y$ there is a member of the collection $p$ such that $p(x)\neq p(y)$. I’ve shown that $\mathbb P_n$ is not dense because it does not separate the points $-1$ and $1$.